# How to get the degree of a node by direction and types using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Concretely, I'm looking for the equivalent to [1] but using Cypher. I guess an approach would be to use

```
START n=node(43) MATCH (n)-[r:KNOWS|LIKES]->() RETURN n, count(r) AS degree
```

However in my use case I need to get (and use) the degrees for potentially many nodes resulting from a more complex query and the approach above doesn't scale.

[1] http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-node-degree.html#rest-api-get-the-degree-of-a-node-by-direction-and-types

Answer (score 0):

Do you care that about limiting to just the `KNOWS` and `LIKES` relationships?

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->() WHERE ID(n) = 43 RETURN n, count(r) AS degree
```

But you would have to have an awful lot of relationships to make this not scale.  If you use an ID then Cypher will go right to the node and then browse out it's relationships.  It doesn't depend on the number of total nodes/relationships, just the number of relationships attached to the node.

I'm not sure if that answers your question, but let me know if you have any specific concerns about the scalability.

Comment: Thanks Brian. But I guess I wasn't clear enough. In my real use case I wouldn't use the ID. I wrote that example as the analogous to the example in [1]. My query would look more like: `MATCH (n: LABEL)-[r:REL_TYPE_1]->(m), (n)-[s:REL_TYPE_2|REL_TYPE_3]->() WITH count(s)*m.some_prop AS score RETURN n ORDER BY score DESC`. Thus I was hoping to have some kind of function in cypher. Alternatively, I'm considering pre-computing degrees that I'm interested and keep them as node properties.

Comment: Pre-computing isn't necessarily a bad idea when performance gets bad.  A couple of things to note, first.  You'll probably want to `MATCH` on `(n:LABEL)` and then `OPTIONAL MATCH` on the two (or more) other paths so you get results when the degree is `0`.

Comment: Secondly, I've recently been exposed to the syntax `RETURN size((n)-[s:REL_TYPE_2|REL_TYPE_3]->())`.  I don't know if that's more performant or not, but it's worth a shot

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately, `size` doesn't help in my case but is good to know it exists. I couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: I want to get degree by edge property. How can I do that ? For example get actors and count of movies they acted in, which acted in between years 1990 to 2000